# No Shadows under menus on application decoration borders and unity panel

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, compiz, 16.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 my system works well, except some minor issues with video drivers for NVIDIA at least. I had to re-install NVIDIA driver for it to work well (as always after the upgrade, though), yet there are still signs of misconfiguration.

There are no shadows under menus in application borders and panel, please look down. Let me know, if anybody experienced anything like this, and if any solution can be found.

Alex.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it has been reported on Launchpad (Ubuntu's bug tracker) here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1574693.

And a fix has been published in the `xenial-proposed` repository (see below for a link on how to enable it), so it should be available to the main repository in your updates in a few days if all goes well:

> Hello Albert, or anyone else affected,
>
> Accepted gtk+3.0 into xenial-proposed. The package will build now and
>   be available at
>   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1 in a
>   few hours, and then in the -proposed repository.
>
> Please help us by testing this new package. See
>   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed for documentation how
>   to enable and use -proposed. Your feedback will aid us getting this
>   update out to other Ubuntu users.
>
> If this package fixes the bug for you, please add a comment to this
>   bug, mentioning the version of the package you tested, and change the
>   tag from verification-needed to verification-done. If it does not fix
>   the bug for you, please add a comment stating that, and change the tag
>   to verification-failed. In either case, details of your testing will
>   help us make a better decision.
>
> Further information regarding the verification process can be found at
>   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/PerformingSRUVerification . Thank you
>   in advance!

Comment: Hello Yann, thank you for posting the package and all the work you and your colleagues do out there. I am going to test if the malfunction still persists after the package installation and will let you know.  Alex.

Comment: Hello Yann, just upgraded to 16.04 from 15.10, and everything works good. Thank you very much for addressing the issue. Alex.

Comment: You are welcome. :) But I didn't work on it. ;)